# ag-grid Angular 4 & ui-router ui-sref in cellRenderer

Tags: ag-grid-ng2

If I want to compile a UI-Router state (using uiSref) in ag-Grid cellRenderer, is it possible?

import { GridOptions } from 'ag-grid/main';

```
public gridOptions: GridOptions;

this.gridOptions = this.utility.initGridOptions([

            {
                headerName: 'Column 1',
                field: 'actions',
                 cellRenderer: function (params) {
                     const html = '<a uiSref="route({id: \'' + params.data.id + '\'})">GO HERE</a>';
                     return html;
                 }

            }
        ]);
```

With the above code, ag-Grid renders the table like so:

```
<a uiSref="route({id: 9999})">GO HERE</a>
```

It's not compiled/resolved. I have one solution already but it's complicated. Is there a simple way that I am missing to get it to render the URL?